# Get sql Id and insert it into another query instantly

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables first called **messages** and the other called **messages_reply**.

I used this code to insert into **messages** table:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `messages` VALUES('', '$id', '$otherId', '')";
$query_run = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
```

I have the first column auto_increment thats why I left it empty by writing **''**

Now i want this auto_increment value that i have inserted to be inserted in the other table called **messages_reply**

Do I have to create another query to return it or there is an instant way to insert it here and there?

Comment: `last_insert_id()`:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: I think its not secured because another user may insert in the same time and i get his Id by mistake

Comment: "The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis.".  Different users would have to be sharing the same connection, which seems unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

you have to select the last id on table messages first, then you can insert that **last id + 1** into messages reply

```
$query_sel_last_id = "SELECT id FROM messages ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 1"; // select the last id
```

after that, you only need to insert to **messages_reply**, remember to plus the value

```
$query_sel_last_id + 1
```

**EDIT:** gordon's solution is better and simpler, `LAST_INSERT_ID()`